# what is difference between microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client and microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.core?

Tags: nuget-package, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

There are two nuget packages for SignalR client:

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/) and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/).

Both ASP.NET Core, but I can't find any information why they both exist.

Probably Client.Core has limited functionality, but this is just my guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Both ASP.NET Core, but I can't find any information why they both exist.

The [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) package depends upon the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/) package.

[image]

And from doc of "ASP.NET Core SignalR .NET Client", we can find that:

*The [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) package is required for .NET clients to connect to SignalR hubs.*

Besides, if you do a test with only installing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core` package in your client app, you would find you can not call `WithUrl` method to configure the HubConnection to use HTTP-based transports to connect to the specified URL.

And it would cause the error, like below.

*'HubConnectionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithUrl' and no accessible extension method 'WithUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'HubConnectionBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Answer (score 0):

As of .Net 8.0 when you install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core will be installed as well. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core should be just a subset which does not have some extended methods like WithURL.